# Не удается загрузить картинку с внутреннего хранилища

Tags: android, java

Сохраняю картинку и записываю её адрес:

```
OutputStream stream = this.context.openFileOutput("icon_"+String.valueOf(this.id),Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        (BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArr, 0, byteArr.length)).compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,90,stream);
        this.icon = "icon_"+String.valueOf(this.id);
        stream.close();
```

Загружаю картинку из адреса:

```
mImageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(data.ads.get(1).icon));
```

mImageView остается пустым. Хотя проверка существования файла говорит, что файл существует. И так же если этот файл дать картинке напрямую (без сохранения в файловую систему), то тоже нормально отображается. Может, не верен формат адреса при загрузке (отличается от сохранения)? Может, надо как-то указывать полный адрес с адресом приложения? Буду благодарен за любую помощь.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте загружать следующим образом:

```
File imgFile = context.getFileStreamPath(data.ads.get(1).icon);
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());
mImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Comment: Да, так работает. Хотя я не понял, что сделал. Спасибо большое!